Function to obtain reflection coefficient of lattice filter
Assume $H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\sum _{i=0}^N b_i z^{-i}$ where $b_0=1$ and $b_i$ is real.  The corresponding lattice form is

\begin{align}
v_i[n] = & \ v_{i-1}[n]+k_iw_{i-1}[n-1] \\
w_i[n] = & \ k_iv_{i-1}[n]+w_{i-1}[n-1] \\
v_0[n] = & \ w_0[n]=x[n] \\
y[n] = & \ w_N[n]
\end{align}
Now assume a list f whose elements are the coefficients of the polynomial $H(z)$. We can obtain the coefficients $k_i$ with the matlab code below
function k = tf2rc(f)
    f = f / f(1); % make sure f is normalized so that f(1)=1
    N = length(f)-1;
    k = zeros(1,N);
    for i = N:-1:1
        k(i) = f(i+1);
        f = (f(1:i) - k(i)*f(end:-1:2)) / (1-k(i)^2);
    end
end

The corresponding Mathematica function I created is
f[x_List] := Module[{a = x/x[[1]], lth = Length[x] - 1}, k = ConstantArray[0., lth]; 
Do[k[[i]] = a[[i + 1]]; a = (a[[1 ;; i]] - k[[i]]  Reverse@a[[2 ;;]])/(1 - k[[i]]^2), {i, lth, 1, -1}]; k]

Now given
x = {2, 2.76, 2.68, 1.2};f[x]

We obtain the coefficients
{0.5, 0.8, 0.6}

I feel the function is too lengthy in Mathematica. Can someone think of an elegant one, better without the loop?

Here is an attempt to rewrite f in slightly more functional manner:
ClearAll[f, h];
h[x : {__?RealValuedNumberQ}] := 
   Divide[Most@x - Last@x  Reverse@Rest@x, 1 - Last@x^2]
h[x : {__?RealValuedNumberQ}] /; First@x == Last@x || First@x == 0 := 
   Array[0 &, Length@x - 1]

f[x : {__?RealValuedNumberQ}] := 
   Last /@ Reverse@Most@NestList[h, Normalize[x, First], Length@x - 1]

f@{2, 2.76, 2.68, 1.2}


{0.5, 0.8, 0.6}

